# How to add an if statement to a Tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()


btn=Button(window, text="Yes", fg='blue')
btn.place(x=100, y=100)
btn=Button(window, text="No", fg='blue')
btn.place(x=250, y=100)
window.title('Test')
window.geometry("400x600+10+10")
window.mainloop()
```

I am trying to create it so that when I press the 'Yes' button it will do something (which I have not yet coded) but I don't know how to save the button press input as a variable or have I got it all wrong?

:)

Comment: Just add a `command=func` to the button then define the function.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Where do i add the 'command=func'?

Comment: look at my answer i specified where and how to use the command=func :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()   

def something():
     print('hello')

btn=Button(window, text="Yes", fg='blue', command = something)
btn.place(x=100, y=100)
btn=Button(window, text="No", fg='blue')
btn.place(x=250, y=100)
window.title('Test')
window.geometry("400x600+10+10")
window.mainloop()
```

clicking on your button will call the function that you put in `command`, which is called `something`, you can put your code in there.

Comment: Hi, I copied your exact code and layout but is said that the word command is invalid syntax.

Comment: fixed it, forgot the comma `,` between `fg='blue'` and `command = something` i edited the post and added it, try it now, and if it works mark it as an answer :)